# SQL server collation change on the instance level

Tags: sql-server, collation

When a database is created from our application, it takes the default Collation. we don't want to pass the collation in the create database script.

A client has a collation set on the instance level that is Case Sensitive. So the database created for our application is in that collation which is something we don't want.

Can they change the collation on the instance level so the database that gets created will have the desired collation and they can change it back to whatever they want? How do we do this on the instance level?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You do NOT want to change the instance default collation. It is super ugly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-server-collation Why can't you just state which collation you want when you create the database? That is the best way deal with it.

Comment: Changing the instance collation is effectively an uninstall and reinstall of SQL Server, What is the issue with specifying the collation your app requires in the `CREATE DATABASE` script?

Comment: your ask is not clear to me atleast..you can change collation at database level as well as server level(instance)..but changing with out testing will have some side effects

Comment: ok. I get it now the complexity of changing the collation on the server. Our applications creates the database, tables and insert data on a button click and it doesn't pass a collation. We wanted it to keep client's default collation. This is the first client who has a "CS" (case sensitive) collation. Unfortunately, the script create a table "abc" and the insert points to "Abc" and fails. So, I was looking for a way to workaround this without a code change in our product just for one client. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that the database is not created by a script run in, say, SQL Management Studio, but a script launched from within the application.

As noted in the comments and another answers changing the server collation is possible but hairy, the best option in a case like this is creating the database empty, changing the collation (either with `ALTER DATABASE` or from Management Studio), and then create the rest of the database.

This would require changing the application, but only the creation of the database itself since the tables will take the collation of the database, not the server collation (and you can do it in a way that works for every client, check if the database exists and that case skip DB creation and proceed with the rest of objects).

As a final warning, note that having a DB with a collation different of the server collation would mean than the DB has a different collation than the tempdb, so if you use temporal tables you would have problems if you have `WHERE`'s or `JOIN`'s mixing temporal and regular tables. For example, supposing that `SerialNumber` is a char column, this query will fail with a collation error:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
JOIN #TempTable ON #TempTable.SerialNumber=Products.SerialNumber
```

If that case you will have to modify the application and change the queries to something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
JOIN #TempTable ON #TempTable.SerialNumber=Products.SerialNumber COLLATE database_default
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the instance collation which would require dropping the databases before changing it. [Here is a link to setting or changing the Server Collation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-server-collation)

You can also do this on a database level. [Here is information on setting or changing collation on the database level.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-database-collation)

You may also want to read [the collation clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations) which can also be applied to tables, columns, and casting expressions among additional options.